# d3 sunburst chart selection rotation not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization, sunburst-diagram

I am creating a d3 sunburst chart that needs to integrate a selection rotation such as the one seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/musically-ut/4678148 with a selection distortion (zooming only partially into a selected path). I have created a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h943x6yu/ which highlights my attempts to combine the two. This chart will distort and spin but the spin is unpredictable. I want the selected path to rotate to the top 12 o'clock position, regardless of of its position on the graph (as seen in the first link). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
if (error) throw error;

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("g");

path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
    .on("click", magnify)
    // .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    // .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
    .each(stash);

var text = g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
.attr('font-size', function(d) {
    if (d.value < 100000) {
        return '10px'
    } else {
        return '20px';
    }
})
.on("click", magnify);

var innerG = d3.selectAll("g.inner");



// Distort the specified node to 80% of its parent.
function magnify(node) {
    text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);
    spin(node);

    if (parent = node.parent) {
        var parent,
            x = parent.x,
            k = 0.8;
        console.log(x)
        parent.children.forEach(function(sibling) {
            x += reposition(sibling, x, sibling === node
              ? parent.dx * k / node.value
              : parent.dx * (1 - k) / (parent.value - node.value));
        });
    } else {
        reposition(node, 0, node.dx / node.value);
    }

    path.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
    .each("end", function(e, i) {
      // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in node
        if (e.x >= node.x && e.x < (node.x + node.dx)) {
        // get a selection of the associated text element
            var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
        // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
            arcText.transition().duration(750)
            .attr("opacity", 1)
            .attr("transform", function() { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")" })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return y(d.y);
            });
        }
    });

}

function spin(d) {
    var newAngle = - (d.x + d.dx / 2);

    innerG
      .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(" + ((180 / Math.PI * newAngle) - 90) + ")");

    path
      .classed("selected", function (x) { return d.name == x.name; });
}

// Recursively reposition the node at position x with scale k.
function reposition(node, x, k) {
    // console.log(node)
    node.x = x;
    if (node.children && (n = node.children.length)) {
        var i = -1, n;
        while (++i < n) x += reposition(node.children[i], x, k);
    }
    return node.dx = node.value * k;
}

// Stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

// Interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
    return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        a.x0 = b.x;
        a.dx0 = b.dx;
        return arc(b);
    };
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out after a lot of tinkering. I don't know if this is the best solution but it works.

I set an x and y variable like so:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, radius]);
```

and then I set my arc like so:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)) })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)) })
    .cornerRadius(function(d) { return 5;});
```

The above was in my original jsFiddle example.

When my original spin function was called (onClick) it ran like so:

```
function spin(d) {
        var newAngle = - (d.x + d.dx / 2);
        console.log('newAngle', newAngle)

        innerG
          .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(" + ((180 / Math.PI * newAngle) - 90) + ")");


    path
      .classed("selected", function (x) { return d.name == x.name; });
}
```

This was giving me an unpredictable spin. After tinkering a bit I realized that if I ran the spin transform through the x variable instantiated earlier then clicked the spin twice it would correct to - 90 degrees every time. At this point I dropped the -90 on the transform and created a promise/then function to run it twice:

```
function spin(d) {

    var spin1 = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
        var newAngle = - x(d.x + d.dx / 2);
        console.log('newAngle', newAngle)

        innerG
          .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(" + ((180 / Math.PI * newAngle)) + ")");
            resolve("Success!");
    });

    spin1.then(function() {
        var newerAngle = - x(d.x + d.dx / 2);
        console.log('newerAngle', newerAngle)

        innerG
          .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(" + ((180 / Math.PI * newerAngle)) + ")");
    })

    path
      .classed("selected", function (x) { return d.name == x.name; });
}
```

This is probably a bit hackie but works very well. View final result here: https://jsfiddle.net/d28nw97x/1/